# Multidimensional array / Session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have built a Show Exhibition booking system, where the exhibitor enters their details, then selects the "Shows" they wish to book including the "Stand Size" and any "Extras" that go with the show. (Stand Sizes & Extras are specific to each show).
This works OK, entering the correct booking details into my database (1 row per show booking, per show).
However i need to add in a Conformation page, before the booking data is Inserted in to the DB (as users are clicking their back button to make corrections, then clicking "book" again so adding duplicates in some cases).

Each booking has 1 x Show, 1 x Stand but multiple x Extras
Several booking (for different shows) can be made at the same time.

I think im on the right track: I am trying to store all the data for each booking into an array (a SESSION array to be specific), so i can then output (in HTML) what is about to be booked. The user then clicks confirm (or edit) and the session data is then extracted/Inserted in to my DB.

I am struggling to get my head around this as I have arrays within the array, as I need to keep the data together, and I dont know how many extras are going to be booked for each show. Is this OK?

Below is the array part of the code (well my test), but it is not working as I expected (and im not fully understanding how to extract the data)

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION[] = array();

$_SESSION[] = array(showID=>1, standID=>s1, extras=>array(x1, x1QT=>2 ,x2, x2QT=>4 ));
$_SESSION[] = array(showID=>2, standID=>s2, extras=>array(x1,x2));

foreach ($_SESSION as $booking) {
    foreach($booking as $showID => $show){
        echo 'Show ID = ' . $show. '<br>';
    }

}
```

i know i need more code in here, but am struggling to work out how i access the correct data from the array, specific to each show.
I dont think i will have a problem building the array, as the code that does this is already working (added in manually above, just for testing).

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be VERY grateful.
It is also entirely possible I am not going about this in the right way at all, so feel free to tell me this, with the way I should be going. (or should I be working on storing all data as hidden form inputs that are passed on submit of "conformation"?)

Answer (score 0):

your array keys & values must be quoted (')

```
$_SESSION[] = array('showID'=>'1', 
                    'standID'=>'s1', 
                    'extras'=>array(
                                    'x1', 
                                    'x1QT'=>'2' ,
                                    'x2', 
                                    'x2QT'=>4 ));

$_SESSION[] = array('showID' => '2', 
                    'standID'=> 's2', 
                    'extras' => array('x1','x2'));
```

Comment: Thanks that is great. 

i was qoting things but through a mistake noticed it still worked without them, so as i thought it looked neater, i removed them :-). But ill add them back now!

I will also do as you say and add the array to $row first. 

could you suggest how i would then be able to access each feild. the foreach loop i have returns `array` for some of the feilds. it also returns more rows than i expect (one for each feild i think).

Thanks again for the help. it is much appreciated